# Amazon Advertising Api - reports data processing (ACOS, ROAS, Organic Sales, Ad Sales)

Tags: amazon-product-api, amazonsellercentral, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to process Amazon data and get some calculated results such as ACOS, ROAS, Organic Sales(direct sales not from ads) and Ad Sales or Ad revenues.

I have pulled data from Amazon Advertising API reports for sponsored products, brands & displays, I also have orders & order items from Amazon Seller Partner API.

For ACOS, I have the cost field from Amazon Advertising api and total sales from Seller partner api, but is this the right formula to use for.

Another case I have is, I need to now the number of sales from ads, eg I have 100 total sales, 40 of them are from ads. From all those data I have, I can't find anything thats related to this, maybe there is another api or service to pull those records.

Another case is ROAS, but I can't find the right formula to calculate this type from Amazon Advertising Data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ACoS is typically total ad spend / total ad sales- not total sales overall.
RoAS is the inverse: total sales / total ad spend.

You also have to consider the scope of your aggregation. Amazon's advertising API can only return 1 day's worth of data. So if you want your aggregated metrics of RoAS and ACoS to be over, say, a month- you could either pull ~30 days of data, or you can build a process to database this data daily and run a query on the database.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Advertising API returns only the sales data from ads and not the total number of sales. For total sales there's a different API called the MWS API which contains the total orders/sales data. You can check it out here:

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html